# document.evaluate with XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE returns undefined

Tags: javascript, xpath, firebug

Firebug prints xpath result as undefined but it is not undefined

```
function xpathTest()
{
 var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
 var result = document.evaluate("//div[text()='Hello']", div1, null, 
                 XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
 console.log(result); // Firebug prints undefined
 console.log(result === undefined); // prints false
 console.log(typeof result); // prints object
 console.log(result.singleNodeValue); // prints Hello
}
```

Html here:

```
<body onload="xpathTest()">
 <div id="div1">
   <div>Hello</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

So actual toString()(?) implementation of xpath result is not correct or is it Firebug's fault?

Comment: Using Chrome, and firefox's built in web console `result` gets shown as `XPathResult`, only shows `undefined` in firebug so it is probably a firebug issue. Using console.dir however makes firebug print out the XPathResult object

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a Firebug issue.

```
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");  
add("Result: " + result); // Result: [object XPathResult]
add("(result === undefined): " + (result === undefined)); 
// (result === undefined): false

add("(typeof result): " + (typeof result)); 
// (typeof result): object

add("result.singleNodeValue: " + result.singleNodeValue); 
// result.singleNodeValue: [object HTMLDivElement]

function add(content)
{
  resultDiv.innerHTML += content + "<br>";
}
```

See [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lrb8j22p/)